# What is a better way to manipulate named values?

Tags: python, variables, iterable

I am thinking about, basically, a way to store data. Something like a table, if Python had tables. For example's sake, I have a list of names that I want to associated with changing values and then manipulate them in expressions, preferably by iteration. Here is an example: three names "foo", "bar" and "baz" are declared, decremented, then changed and again decremented (in my project, I have lists with a dozen names but the principle is the same).

Way 1: variables and if-elif-else:

```
foo = 123
bar = 456
baz = 789

def chooser(n):
    if n == 0:
        return foo - 1
    elif n == 1:
        return bar - 1
    elif n == 2:
        return baz - 1

for i in range(3):
    print chooser(i)

foo = 1
bar = 2
baz = 3

for i in range(3):
    print chooser(i)
```

Way 2: dictionary

```
data = {'foo':123, 'bar':456, 'baz':789}

for i in ('foo', 'bar', 'baz'):
    print data[i] - 1

data['foo'] = 1
data['bar'] = 2
data['baz'] = 3

for i in ('foo', 'bar', 'baz'):
    print data[i] - 1
```

However, I strongly suspect there is an even better and more pythonic way to do the same thing. Can the community please come with further alternatives, if there are any?

Comment: "apparently it will not work at all" How so? Should work just fine. Please explain what exactly you want, and what is the problem. Do you want the values in the list or dict be updated when new values are assigned to the original variables?

Comment: so many questions: what are you trying to have your function do? what are examples of inputs and outputs you're looking for? what is the point of your`for` loop? It will only every execute once since you `return` something on the first iteration.

Comment: What is the input of chooser? What is the expected output?

Comment: Maybe we're looking for `yield` here?

Comment: It would be better if you used a more realistic example - this will always return foo ^ 2.

Comment: ok! pls see edit: is there a way to eliminate if-elif-else?

Comment: This code can't "work as expected". There are syntax errors and you'll always get back `foo ^ 2` (BTW, are you sure you mean `^` and not `**`?).

Comment: @user6570767 what do you mean? your code loops over 0-1 and immediately returns the result for one? why do you have a for loop there?

Comment: Learn [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: thx. will re-do the question from scratch

Comment: It's unclear what your trying to achieve. Please clarify this in your question.

Comment: What do you mean "a direct call for an iterable"?

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough and it's on the brink of being closed.

Comment: What's that "just to catch illegal input" doing there? Your function takes no input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, there is a more pythonic way. It's called using `.items()`. Seriously dude, can't you try and look up `dict` in the Python official docs?

```
for key, value in data.items():
    print(data[key] - 1)
```

---

## Old Answer

Use a dictionary. It can map strings to other objects, like so:

```
>>> data = {'foo' : 123, 'bar' : 456, 'baz' : 789}
>>> data['foo']
123
```

Your second way doesn't even work, even though you say it works. You just pretended like it does work. You don't know how to fundamentally use a dictionary.

---

## Old Old Answer

1. It's pythonic, not "pythonista". Pythonista describes somebody experienced with Python.
2. Don't use global variables from within functions! I see no reason why you couldn't pass `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` as arguments.
3. I don't know where you got "...putting in a tuple or dictionary but apparently it will not work at all" from. It will work. Just don't use a dictionary because that's not what you want. You can access a tuple's elements using `tuple_name[array_index]`. Remember: array indices start at zero. To create a tuple in your case you'll need `(123, 456, 789)`
4. It's still unclear what you're trying to achieve here. **Tell us what you want to achieve.** Why even use the function? Why is it called `chooser`? Why not loop over a tuple like this? :

   ```
   data = (123, 456, 789)
   for element in data:
       print(element - 1)
   ```

---

## Old Old Old Answer

I think you have a basic misunderstanding of the concepts in that code snippet.

`foo, bar, baz = 123, 456, 789` does **not**  create a list, it assigns `123` to `foo`, `456` to `bar`, and likewise for `baz`.

Your looping over `range(2)` - this is a loop! It'll go over each of the values `0-1`, so `2` will never be reached and what's your 'illegal input' thing doing there?

You have forgotten the argument list in your functioon definition - required for any function, even if it has no arguments. It should be `def chooser():`.

And by the way, the `^` operator isn't exponentiation - it's bit shift, which is an advanced concept you shouldn't be learning now. To do exponentiation you must use the `**` operator.

And what did you expect? `chooser()` will always return `123^2`. (which is `121`, the result of the bit shift)

It's unclear what your trying to achieve. Please clarify this in your question.

`chooser` does not ask the user for input, as the name would imply. I think you misunderstood that `range()` gets input. It doesn't: it returns an iterable (0, 1).

If you wanted to store some variables in a tuple you could write `data = (123, 456, 789)`. **Then instead of writing `foo`, you'd write `data[0]`, and instead of writing `bar`, you'd write `data[1]`.** Etc. for `baz`.

Comment: correct. did a bad job. ok, will have to come with a better question. everyone, thx, will be back

Comment: @user6570767 your code doesn't even run and you say "it works as expected".

Comment: can you check it now pls?

Comment: @user6570767 your previous code snippet meant nothing like the new one. And why did you have `^` in your previous code? Learn to create a [mcve].

Comment: " your previous code snippet meant nothing like the new one" - can you pls explain a bit how can I make it more clear? I am trying to come with a more concize way to do the same thing as this code does, that's it. your last suggestion per tuple is fine, except that I wish to keep the naming.

Comment: @user6570767 tell me what you're trying to do. see my updated answer

Comment: thanx. points taken. tried to describe the problem in a totally different way. albeit more wordy.

Comment: @user6570767 please please use proper spelling, grammar, and punctuation

Comment: @user6570767 it matters not if you prefer iteration. you are still describing what your code does. Tell me what you want the result to be. What's your goal? I have the power of voting to reopen this question.

Comment: Here is the workflow I am trying to construct: 1. name values. 2. process them in a batch by name. 3. change values by name. 4. process them in a batch by name. and so on. If python had 'tables' - like, say, Excel - it would pretty much be like having a table and looking up current values in it for use. Again, sorry if this is not clear enough, but at this moment it is the best I can imagine the situation.

Comment: @user6570767 tables = nested arrays; do you really need names? you can just use a list! Do you fundamentally need names for a fundamental reason? It makes everything harder to work with

Comment: I could use a list, but need names for consistency. Different functions use different subsets of names, and if lists are used, numeric indices point to different values. A name is pretty much a human-readable unique id that is used across the project.

Comment: @user6570767 see my updated answer

Comment: @user6570767 you could have a dictionary mapping list indices to human readable names

Comment: So basically there is no better way to do it as in my second example?

Comment: @user6570767 your second example doesn't even run. Are you sure you're writing the right langauge??

Comment: Yes, it doesn't. Had to change names to strings, works now.

Comment: @user6570767 see my updated answer. you are seriously confusing me

Comment: lol. It does run in Python 2.7.

Comment: @Amal.R that's before the example was updated to make it run!

Comment: @uoɥʇʎpʎzɐɹc Oh! Ok.

Comment: @user6570767 If my answer solved your problem, click the checkmark below the vote box and upvote my answer. I don't get paid to do this.

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC Exactly. It's of no use spending a lot of time trying to answer this one single question.

Comment: @user6570767 did it fix your problem? I'm getting frustrated and I'm about to leave. This isn't worth +25 rep.

Comment: thank you! In fact I upvoted you when you just gave this answer. I tried to upvote again, just to make sure. .items is a nicer way to do the same, except that the output is in a different order, but with names, that does not matter much. thank you for your time! 

[('baz', 3), ('foo', 1), ('bar', 2)]
2
0
1

Comment: @user6570767 now please click the check mark

Comment: @user6570767 you're welcome. dictionary is unordered btw

Comment: yes, it is - thanks! i really appreciate your patience, and it helped me learn a thing. )

Comment: @user6570767 one more thing - please search the python official documentation before posting. docs.python.org

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC I do, but is not always obvious how a given method applies to your situation - this is when it helps to ask

Comment: @user6570767 your initial question was extremely confusing. actually run your example code. tell us what you want done. Seriously, read this guide! [mcve]

Comment: @user6570767 I recommend PyCharm for you as an editor. Try it out, it's free.

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC *thumb up* using it now ) as per confusion, I could tell it - takes time to learn to speak so that one can be understood, especially if you are confused yourself )